# How to let htaccess distinguish between files and ids

Tags: .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not an existing dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not an existing file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f # and page.php exists

# redirect to the physical page
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

# otherwise, redirect to serve.php
RewriteRule ^ /serve.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./serve.php?id=$1
```

So in the first part of the code I just turn http into https. My aim is that I can use urls without an `.php` but in my old code I had the problem that if I did so, it was used as an id for my serve.php page. So if use `https://example.com/contact` it was like `https://example.com/serve.php?id=contact` but I want it to work as `https://example.com/contact.php` but on the other side I want that ids that arent directions or file should still work as ids. My old code was...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./serve.php?id=$1

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# skip rules below this for files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]


# rewrite to the physical php page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# otherwise, redirect to serve.php
RewriteRule ^/?$ serve.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ serve.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: God bless you, finally somebody who dont reports me for a duplicate but helps for real. Go on like that!